# Enforce encoding of output files with Teradata TPT Export

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I am looking for options if it is somehow possible to enforce a specific encoding (ANSI/UTF8) with TPT Export for the output .dat data file.

The exported data file is required to be in ANSI format, Currently the same TPT export script generate files with different encoding in different env. (Dev/Test/Prod), possibly due to default environment settings.

I have tried CHARACTER SET ASCII and resulted in UTF8 on one machine while ANSI on the other. (Server OS AIX)

The other option is to use some post script to convert the out file to desired encoding.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by "file encoding" or why it would differ. Perhaps try adding `USING CHARACTER SET ASCII` prefix on the `DEFINE JOB`? If that's not the solution, please edit the question to include more information / examples of the issue and what you want.

Comment: I need to export data into .dat file and required encoding for .dat file is ANSI. Using TPT 15.10 with AIX machine. Tried both (ASCII/UTF8) in CHARACTER SET option doesn't make any difference.

Comment: How are you determining that the encoding is UTF8? If a file contains only single-byte characters with the high order bit zero then it would be valid to consider it either 7-bit ASCII or UTF8. If some bytes have the high order bit set, that might indicate UTF8 encoding or maybe just an 8-bit extension to ASCII like ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 or Teradata LATIN.